# Facebook4j library post photo issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook4j library for integrating facebook api in java. However, I face issues when I try to post a photo with a place attribute.

```
Media media = new Media(new File(<image-path-here>));
PhotoUpdate update = new PhotoUpdate(media);
update.message("photo upload test");
update.setPlace("Bangalore");
facebook.postPhoto(update);
```

But I get the following exception:`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [post] in context with path [/Sample] threw exception [message - An unknown error has occurred.FacebookException{statusCode=500, errorType='OAuthException', errorMessage='An unknown error has occurred.', errorCode=1, errorSubcode=-1, version=2.2.0}`

Turns out that without the 'setplace' its works completely fine. I am not sure if I am doing the right way and searched the web to get some samples as well. But could not find one, can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong here? I can post the photo on facebook without setting the location but I need to set location for image.

Thanks

Comment: guys has anyone found a solution for the above issue? I am really struggling here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my solution, I upload the image to server and upload that file to facebook. you can see the below example.

```
    /**
 * NOTE: Post Photo To Wall Facebook
 * @param String idToObject
 * @param File filePhoto (This is real file from server)
 * @return List<String>
 */
public String postToWallPhoto(String idToObject, UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    PhotoUpdate photoUpdate = null;
    try {
        Media media=new Media(uploadedFile.getFile());
        photoUpdate = new PhotoUpdate(media);
        photoUpdate.message(postItem.getGroupMessage());

        String idPost = facebook.postPhoto(idToObject, photoUpdate);

    } catch (FacebookException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return idPost;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sample code. What I want is to able to add location to the image. Can you please tell me if this works with "setplace()" method as in my question?

Comment: sorry I have not tried it with setPlace() before. You may test it with your code

Comment: Thanks @minh-nguyen. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
PostUpdate post= update = new PostUpdate("@Minh Nguyen")
        .picture(new URL("Img_url"));
facebook.postFeed(id,post);
```

Comment: The above works completely fine, thank you. But my requirements are 1. Image should come from local storage, 2. The location of image captured should be present. I have not been able to find any solution till date, so I have added location in the message/story. Anyhow thanks for your input! :)